# Is it grammatical to use the phrase "floating and lost in the dark"?

Tags: participles

> **Floating and lost in the dark**, everyone's morale started to crack.

In the sentence, is the phrase **floating and lost in the dark** a dangling participle?
Is it grammatical to use the phrase **floating and lost in the dark**?

Comment: We might need a little more context. Maybe a link to where you found this ? Or a little more context before "Floating and lost in the dark". Maybe it has got something about water or boats or ships...things that are related to floating, generally

Comment: @Varun KN. The context is:Everyone assumed the other swimmers had drowned.

Comment: These danglers are used by native speakers every day; teachers correct them—"the phrase must modify the subject of the main clause" (here, "morale", and morale can neither float nor be lost in the dark)—but teachers are losing that battle, along with many others :)